# Why linspace was named like that in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning python and numpy. The docstring of numpy.linspace says

> Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
>
> Returns `num` evenly spaced samples, calculated over the interval
>   [`start`, `stop`].

So I guess the "space" part of linspace means "space". But what does "lin" stand for?

Comment: Probably an abbrevation for linear spaced vector, same as MATLAB.

Comment: linspace is linear space as opposed to another distribution such as logarithmic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linear space. So in other words, from a straight line over an interval we take n samples.

Answer (score 2):

The name `linspace` for a “linear space” of *n* points between two endpoints was created by MATLAB:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html

NumPy then followed, using the same name so that folks already familiar with vector programming in MATLAB could use the same routine in Python.